# Manually add ng animate to element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to manually add NG animate to an element?

For example I want to add ng-enter and ng-leave when a ng-class is added or removed. But I also need ng-enter-active and ng-leave-active classes that gives me more control over the animation process.

Comment: Can you give more information about your problem

Comment: So what I want is when for example I click on a button the ng-enter will be added to an element and after the animation has finished it will add also add ng-enter-active class (or the other way around I forgot). This gives me more control over the animation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. But you've to do some trick here like following.

Use https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ for your application. It has nice animations by default. If you add this to your element, whenever the element inserted to the dom, there will be an animation.

But here in your scenario, add animate class whenever you add or remove class from your elements based on your condition. The sample code is below.

```
   <div ng-class="AddClass?'yourClass animated fadeIn':'animated fadeOut removedClass'"> 
</div>
```

Comment: But this way it doesn't add the ng-enter, ng-enter-active, ng-leave and ng-leave-active classes though. These are the classes I need for the more advanced animation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove a directive based on a class change in ng-class. However since you are applying a class in ng-class based on a condition, you could use that same expression in ng-if to include ng-enter or ng-leave.

Comment: But what I really want is the behavior of angular to also add the ng-enter-active or ng-leave-active.